# Linux mail command to bcc multiple addresses?

Tags: linux, email, bcc

I am using linux mail command to send an automated email to a bunch of people once per week.
I want each one of the recipients to be BCC'ed.

I am trying this command:

```
mail -v -s "Email Subject" -b george@gmail.com, maria@email.com, gina@correo.com, asher@texting.com -- -f jpatino@azucarcolombia.com < /pathTo/dir/emailText.txt
```

But get this error:

```
You must specify direct recipients with -s, -c, or -b.
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to put them all in a single argument by quoting it.

```
mail -v -s "Email Subject" -b 'george@gmail.com, maria@email.com, gina@correo.com, asher@texting.com' -- -f jpatino@azucarcolombia.com < /pathTo/dir/emailText.txt
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. However, I get a bounce message when it tries to send to `-f`. Why do you have that in the regular recipient list?

Comment: I use -f to specify the "from" parameter in the email

Comment: Everything after `--` is the recipients.

Comment: Like I said, it works but I get a bounce message saying that delivery to `-f@mydomain` failed. All the other recipients get the message.

Comment: There's no `-f` option for setting the `From` header in http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are multiple versions of the mail command.

mail (GNU Mailutils) 3.7 has an append option to add headers and values directly without piping them in. Just add the headers you need there, e.g. bcc:

echo "Just testing my sendmail" | mail -s "Sendmail test" test@to.com --append=Bcc:test@bcc.com,other@bcc.com

[How to send mail through BCC in UNIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50831023/how-to-send-mail-through-bcc-in-unix/71529997#71529997)

Comment: This works with the standard "mail" command in Ubuntu.